# a perfect wrapper for any generic type `T`

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics

I am trying to create a perfect wrapper for any generic type `T`:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')

class PerfectWrapper(typing.Generic[T], T): # ERROR
    def __init__(self, value: T, index: tuple):
        T.__init__(self, value)
        self.__index = index

    @property
    def index(self):
        return self.__current_index
```

unfortunately the above code throws an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-5c80ceb6eeaf> in <module>
      3 T = typing.TypeVar('T')
      4 
----> 5 class PerfectWrapper(typing.Generic[T], T): # ERROR
      6     def __init__(self, value: T, index: tuple):
      7         T.__init__(self, value)

TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

and I have no idea (other than mixing both metaclasses) on how to fix this problem.
I need to inherit from the class `T`, to "expose" `T`'s properties/methods at the `PerfectWrapper` level.

obviously property: `self.__index` and method `self.index()` are there to "extend" class with additional information. In its most basic version, this wrapper might as well have them commented out.